# Control keyboard backlight indicator in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard-backlight

My keyboard has variable automatic keyboard backlighting -- it adjusts the light intensity to the environment. I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10.

*Ubuntu now flashes a keyboard backlight icon every time the brightness auto adjusts.* This happens every 10 seconds, which is distracting. I want to turn it off.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To avoid the flashing backlight icon, download and install the latest system updates to Ubuntu.*

This has now fixed my issue with flashing backlight. As it's not a direct answer to the question -- how to control whether the backlight indicator shows at all -- I'll consider marking another answer correct if one is written. For me, however, this is no longer an issue.